# Angularjs - checkbox to update SPAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

thanks for looking.

I'm new to Angular and am having some issues.

I have some checkboxes that when clicked, will display some text inside a SPAN tag.

Thats it.  I just cannot get it to work!

[Default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo1V9.png)

[Selected Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9jgj.png)

So to Clarify - When the user checks the checkboxes - the the text over the image changes (border added).

Hope this makes sense.

Here's my code so far:

```
 <span id="PartyWall1" style="position:absolute;top:42px; left:141px; font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:12px;">Wall 1</span>
        <span id="PartyWall2" style="position:absolute;top:345px; left:141px; font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:12px;">Wall 2</span>
        <span id="PartyWall3" style="position:absolute;top:175px; left:85px; font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:12px;">Wall 3</span>
        <span id="PartyWall4" style="position:absolute;top:175px; left:204px; font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:12px;">Wall 4</span>




  <div class=" col-lg-12 col-md-12" ng-if="IsPartWall">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-icon-right">
                                <label>Which wall(s) are Party wall(s)? </label>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-small">
                                    <input name="cb1" id="cb1" type="checkbox" ng-model="objPostData.Wall1" tabindex="12" value="123"/>

                                    <label for="cb1">wall-1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-small">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" ng-model="objPostData.Wall2" tabindex="13" value="123" name="cb2"/>
                                    <label for="cb2">wall-2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-small">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" ng-model="objPostData.Wall3" tabindex="14" value="123" name="cb3"/>
                                    <label for="cb3">wall-3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-small">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" ng-model="objPostData.Wall4" tabindex="15" value="123" name="cb4"/>
                                    <label for="cb4">wall-4</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive about the exact behavior expected and source of text

Comment: *" I just cannot get it to work"* show what you tried ... the idea here is to help fix **your code**

Comment: Did you want to actual text to change, or did you just want one of the walls to be highlighted, like the color changes from red to green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like something to be displayed or hidden on top of model changes, you need to use `ng-if`/`ng-show`/`ng-hide` on that something. Like this:

```
<span id="PartyWall1" ng-if="objPostData.Wall1">Wall 1</span>
```

Comment: think they might want `ng-class` for *"border added"*

Comment: I see there 'will display some text inside' not something about styling :)

Comment: Thanks guys.  See the actual project here.  You will see the behaviour that I am talking about.

Comment: You will need to Select "Timber Frame" from the "Type of construction" drop down to see the checkboxes.  Also  If you use the textboxes "floor width A" and "Floor width B" you will see how it should work.